# Spring Boot @ControllerAdvice only works under strange circumstances

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, exception

We have the following issue. When we created a global `ExceptionHandler` with `@ControllerAdvice`, we started to get following `Exception` every time we pass a `Long` to the controller and let Spring Boot do the conversion.

```
"Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.example.controlleradvice.model.Location'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:"
```

Without the global `ExceptionHandler` it works just fine and we don't undestand why.

The global `ExceptionHandler`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class GlobalControllerAdvice {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final IndexService indexService;

    @ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
    public ModelAndView globalException(final Exception ex, final HttpServletRequest request) {
     //   userService.getActiveUser().ifPresent(System.out::print);
        return new ModelAndView("index")
                .addObject("viewModel", indexService.getIndexViewModelWithErrorMessage(ex));
    }
```

MvcConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] DEFAULT_STATIC_RESOURCES = {
            "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
            "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/"
    };
    @Getter
    private static Path documentPath;
    @Getter
    private static Path originalImagePath;
    @Getter
    private static Path resourceImagePath;
    @Getter
    private static Path temporaryPath;
    @Getter
    private static String documentWebUrl;
    @Getter
    private static String imageWebUrl;
    @Getter
    private static String imageOriginalUrl;


    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        requestMappingHandlerAdapter.setIgnoreDefaultModelOnRedirect(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler(getDocumentWebUrl() + "/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:" + getDocumentPath() + "/")
                .setCachePeriod(3600)
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new GzipResourceResolver())
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
        registry.addResourceHandler(getImageWebUrl() + "/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:" + getResourceImagePath() + "/")
                .setCachePeriod(3600)
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new GzipResourceResolver())
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
        registry.addResourceHandler(getImageOriginalUrl() + "/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:" + getOriginalImagePath() + "/")
                .setCachePeriod(3600)
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new GzipResourceResolver())
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations(DEFAULT_STATIC_RESOURCES)
                .setCachePeriod(3600)
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new GzipResourceResolver())
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }

}
```

SecurityConfig:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final SecurityUserService securityUserService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/fonts/**", "/scripts/**", "/styles/**",
                        "/css/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll()
                .and().csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/**");
        http.sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false)
                .expiredUrl("/login")
                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(securityUserService);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public static ServletListenerRegistrationBean httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }

}
```

The controller with the defective route:

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("show")
public class ShowController {

    private final IndexService indexService;

    @GetMapping
    public String showWithId(final @RequestParam Location location, final Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("viewModel", indexService.getIndexViewModel(location));
        return "index";
    }
}
```

UserService:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Optional<User> getActiveUser() {
        final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null || authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        return userRepository.findByUsername(authentication.getName());
    }
}
```

To make it even harder for us the understand the underlying mechanism, we found 5 different ways to bypass the problem, without understanding the problem itself.

We've built an Spring Boot Example reproducing the problem and added it to gitlab. That's the [master branch](https://gitlab.com/Maregrim/controllerAdvice/tree/master) where the Error occurs. 
And here's one [Branch with the MvcConfig moved](https://gitlab.com/Maregrim/controllerAdvice/tree/issue1-move-MvcConfig) to another directory.

Any hints about what the real problem is would be much appreciated!

Comment: For starters your `MvcConfig` is a bit strange. Do you really want to auto wire the request mapping in the same configuration that create said bean? Also do you really want to disable the Spring Boot MVC defaults (that is what `@EnableWebMvc` does it stops Spring Boot from applying its default configuration). The auto wiring could / will lead to eager init of the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` leading to weird results. I would suggest remove the `@EnableWebMvc`, the injection of the `RequestHandlingMappingAdapter` and configure that thing through `application.properties`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We need the `@EnableWebMvc` for our RessourceHandlers, but your suggestion was helpful. We now set the option in the Initializer and it's working fine - no strange behaviour anymore.

Comment: You don't need `@EnableWebMvc` for that. That is part of the `WebMvcConfigurer` and you can have that as a regular `@Component` or `@Configuration` to have it influence the resource handlers. So no you don't need that. Also to set that property just add `spring.mvc.ignoreDefaultModelOnRedirect=true` (which is actually the default when using Spring Boot with the auto configuration). Basically what I'm saying is that you should work with the framework and you are trying to work around it...

Comment: Ok, got it. You are totally right. When i tried to remove the `@EnableWebMvc` earlier, it crashed. I must have missed something. I tried it again, the same way you suggested and it works just fine. Thanks for your help. I feel much more comfortable without the `@EnableWebMvc`.